# problem saving date to database mysql using jquery datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, datepicker

this is the code i have used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){     
            $("input#txtDate").datepicker({ altField: 'input#txtDate', altFormat: 'yy-dd-mm' }); 
    }); 

</script>
```

at the time of filling the data to adapter it shows me this error
"Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime"
how to fix this.
i need to show the date in gridview in this format:
eg. may-25 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datepicker and database are stored data of datetime type and input field is text which is not validated to be proper datetime. Before storing to database convert input text to datetime using:

```
$("input#txtDate").datepicker("setDate", $("input#txtDate").val())
```

This will correctly transform input string to datetime. Then store into database the following value of datetime type:

```
$("input#txtDate").datepicker().val()
```

or convert it to desired format before.

Answer (score 0):

Convert date to format YYYY-MM-DD
or in javascript:

```
$("input#txtDate").datepicker({ altField: 'input#txtDate', altFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reply to Danzan/user755230.  Sorry, can't see how to thread comments.  ://

For anyone else who stumbles across this - altField and altFormat will create a second, hidden input with a correctly formatted date in it.  So you have one formatted for the user (e.g. "02/29/2012" and one formatted for the database ("2012-02-29").  Use the "txtDate" value from the form and all should work right.

It does seem to just need two y's though ('yy-mm-dd').

All the options for the jQuery Datepicker are here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker

Comment: You need 50 reputation to comment on post. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment